# How do languages represent UTF-8 under the hood?

Tags: c++, utf-8, character-encoding

I've recently watched [Tom Scott from Computerphile talk about UTF-8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MijmeoH9LT4) and after that and a bit of research understand that UTF-8 can be used to encode characters in up to 6 bytes, using the following headers for each byte:

```
0xxx xxxx    # 1 Byte character
110x xxxx    # 2 Byte character
1110 xxxx    # 3 Byte character
1111 0xxx    # 4 Byte character
1111 10xx    # 5 Byte character
1111 110x    # 6 Byte character
```

And then using `10xx xxxx` to express the extra bytes (I'm aware that [RFC3629](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629) restricted this to only ever go up to 4 bytes).

Am I right in understanding that this then allows 2,164,286 different characters to be encoded (disregarding any reserved characters)?

```
0xxx xxxx    # 7 bits                      =>       128
110x xxxx    # 5 bits + 6 bits   = 11 bits =>     2,048
1110 xxxx    # 4 bits + 6*2 bits = 16 bits =>    65,536
1111 0xxx    # 3 bits + 6*3 bits = 21 bits => 2,097,152
             #                             == 2,164,864
```

In theory I could use a `char` array to store a UTF-8 encoded string, or I could instead use a fixed length encoding like UTF-32 and use any 4 byte type such as `unsigned long` to encode each UTF-8 encoded character, but this would increase memory dramatically for text which only uses UTF-8 characters encoded with 1 or 2 bytes.

I believe `std::string` allows storing of UTF-8 and this will result in `size` and `length` returning byte lengths, but if UTF-8 can represent varying lengths of character, how do languages (we'll take C++ to limit the scope of this question) encode these characters internally (such as in `std::string`)?

Comment: There are APIs who are responsible for converting from and to. eg: `MultiByteToWideChar` and `WideCharToMultiByte`.

Comment: @Raindrop7 that may be true but it doesn't really answer the question about what's going on in the background

Comment: Correct, Unicode currently only allows 21 bits worth of codepoints (and of those only 17 planes of 2^16 code points are actually specified, out of a possible 32).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An UTF-8 string is a sequence of bytes (that is, of `char`-s or `uint8_t` in C++) following some restrictions (so not every sequence of bytes is a valid UTF-8 string; if you get some string from outside which claims that it is UTF-8, you should validate it).

So you can use `std::string`-s to represent UTF-8 strings (provided you are sure they are valid UTF-8).

You may use some UTF-8 library (e.g. [libunistring](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/manual/libunistring.html) or [Glib Unicode Manipulation](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Unicode-Manipulation.html)) above them.

In other words, UTF-8 can be seen as a *convention* on how to use strings (of `char`-s).

Of course, be aware that the number of bytes (e.g. the `size()`  of a `std::string`) is *not* the number of UTF-8 characters. And you can't use ordinary iterators to iterate on UTF-8 characters (or their Unicode equivalent).

You might find some more UTF-8 aware C++ libraries (e.g. [Glibmm ustring](https://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/unstable/classGlib_1_1ustring.html)-s in Gtkmm) or libraries representing Unicode strings otherwise (e.g. [QString](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html)-s in Qt).

BTW, UTF-8 (and Unicode) is quite complex to render properly on screen or paper (so you need some libraries for that). You may have in the same string a mix of various languages (English, Russian, Arabic, Chinese) some of which are changing directions. You may have combining characters (accents, etc). Unicode is quite complex (and I don't know most of it, because I don't know most human languages; I can only speak and read English, French, Russian. I can decipher some greek letters. I know only very few Hebraic letters. And Chinese is completely foreign to me).

See also http://utf8everywhere.org/ and wikipages on [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) and [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).

Comment: So if I were to use `std::string` to store valid UTF-8, it would still in essence just be stored as a sequence of `char`s rather than some other data type (that is, does `std::string` **always** just store a sequence of `char`s)?

Comment: Of course. You could decide to use strings of Unicode characters (e.g. of `uint32_t`). You probably don't want to do this.

Comment: And then there is the whole can of worms of combining Unicode "characters" into a single "character" to be output.  eg é can be 1 or 2 characters.

Comment: Yes, of course! UTF-8 is complex (and Unicode is complex to render: think of mixing left-to-right and right-to-left languages in the same string, e.g. an UTF-8 string containing Arabic, Russian and English....)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Related to your comment and last edit, the video that got me onto the UTF-8 one was the [internationalisation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0j74jcxSunY) which describes issues like these

Answer (score 3):

The C++ standard does not address correct UTF8 handling, but there are libraries that enable iteration over strings by codepoints (the actual characters, as opposed to bytes).

Usually the text is stored as an array of bytes (some curious optimizations such as [tagged pointer strings](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-07-31-tagged-pointer-strings.html) are possible), and lightweight `string views` that provide correct handling of codepoints are usually added on top of that. For example, Swift programming language [employs this technique](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string.characterview).

As for

> or I could instead use a fixed length encoding like UTF-32 and use any
>   4 byte type such as unsigned long to encode each UTF-8 encoded
>   character

C++11 now provides `std::u8string`, `std::u16string` and `std::u32string` for convenience. There is also `std::wstring` which should generally be avoided in portable code, as the size of `wchar_t` is compiler-defined, not standard-defined.

Answer (score 2):

You got straight to the right point. C++ does not represent UTF-8, as far as I'm aware it doesn't handle it at all. Therefore it is just a convention, the one that actually represent it is the one who produce and consume the UTF-8.

Now as you said UTF-8 is oriented around bytes, which allow you to use tools in C++ such as std::string, which is just an array of bytes.
Of-course, if you will just send the string to a random library, which isn't aware of the standard, many things can go wrong. The size of the string as mentioned in some of the other answer here, but even worse, non ASCII character are very likely to result in weird behavior, as those character have more than one byte in them.

Now the nice thing about UTF-8 is has the same representation  for all the characters up to value 128 (which include all the English characters). For this reason, if the producer of the string is not UTF-8 aware, but the consumer of it does, things will still work.

There are many libraries that have done this job already, and they provide either special types for UTF-8 strings, or read a std::string as a UTF-8 string. The standard itself gives you strings were each character can be more than one byte such as `std::u8string`, `std::u16string` and `std::u32string`, none of them really helps in the case of UTF-8 as the characters size vary in this standard.

Finally a very good article about this topic, which also cover what you should do when passing strings over the net: [The Absoultly minimum every developer must know about unicode](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)